# How can I force my 48Mpix Android camera phone to save images at full resolution?

Tags: resolution, cameraphones, megapixels, android

I have a Mi A3 phone camera. This has a 48Mpix sensor, but I am disappointed in the detail captured compared to, for example, a Sony phone with a 12Mpix sensor.

[image: backside 1]

Now what I notice from image properties in Mi A3 is despite the camera being 48 Mpix, when it is normally taking pics  it is taking them as lower resolution per some interinal pre-defined logic. The image captured is  7Mp, 9 MP, or 12 Mp — and this is not in my control.

I want to know how can I capture photos with 12Mp or higher resolution from Mi phone *always*. I want to capture more information in images than the phone's default camera captures.

A friend of mine suggested to use Google camera app
 from https://getdroidtips.com/download-google-camera-for-mi-a3-apk-download/
 to have stable megapixels all the time as I face the problem above.

Comment: It sounds like the question is "how do I force the Xiao I phone to save pictures in the full 48Mpix resolution", right? I'm not sure what all of the Sony pictures lend to this.

Comment: Yes the question is like this

Comment: I'm going to edit it down to focus on that. I think this will get you better changes at a helpful answer.

Comment: Did you try your friend's advice? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Xiaomi Note 7 with likely the same 48Mpix sensor. It take 12Mpix pictures by default (a group of 2x2 pixels is averaged and taken as a single pixel, this is called pixel-binning). There is an option in the camera to take 48Mpix pictures (it appears only in "Pro" mode). I won't use it often because the results are worse than with the 12Mpix setting(*): the "native" 12Mpix picture is better than the 48Mpix one scaled down to 12Mpix. My guess is there is a lot more noise in the sensor data and the camera has to do a lot more processing.

(*) at least in the bleak November light we have in Paris. One a bright sunny day, perhaps...